# How do I template a function typedef using an alias declaration?

Tags: c++, typedef, using-declaration

I'm simply trying to convert my current typedef:

```
typedef void (Foo::*CallbackName)(int arg);
```

Into a function alias, which I have looking like:

```
template <class T>
using T_CallbackName = void(T::*CallbackName)(int arg);
```

Is this correct?  Alias declarations seem straightforward, but function typedefs have weird syntax, and it's not clear to me how to template them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
template <class C>
using T_CallbackName = void (C::*)(int);
```

You can let `arg` if you want, but `CallbackName` should be removed.

Btw, your first `typedef` can be written:

```
using CallbackName = void (Foo::*)(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use auto to define funtion pointer:

> const auto T_CallbackName = Foo::CallbackName

or function reference

> auto& T_CallbackName = Foo::CallbackName

notice this will still work even if you change number of callback parameters